# Vercel Next JS add Stripe listener webhook

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, vercel

I am making an eshop in Next JS and I am using stripe payment system. I want to see if the payment has been completed or cancelled. Then I create an order and update the status paid or not.

localhost package.json

```
"stripe-listen-web": "stripe listen --events checkout.session.completed --forward-to localhost:3000/api/orders/webhook"
```

I run the application on localhost this way and it works.
localhost start my app command

```
npm run stripe-listen & npm run dev
```

But I don't know how to implement this in vercel. Because vercel build project and then server is not runnig.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you're running your project locally or deployed to Vercel, you should be running the Stripe CLI locally.

> `npm run stripe-listen`

While you defined `stripe-listen-web` I don't think this is how you should do this. You should instead run `stripe listen` locally after installing the CLI, using `--forward-to` ([docs](https://docs.stripe.com/webhooks#local-listener)) to point relay the events to your local/remote endpoint. If I've misunderstood what you're trying to do, please share more about this.

The CLI `listen` command is meant only for development purposes, and should *not* be run on a server. Once your endpoint is working the way you want, you should [register your endpoint](https://docs.stripe.com/webhooks#register-webhook) on the hosted environment and Stripe will deliver the events directly (ie, not via the CLI).

Comment: Stripe provides own webhook listener on their websites. I noticed right now. Thanks